# How can I change the selected parameters of another Jenkins pipeline using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

If you do it using Job DSL:

```
    pipelineJob('job-B') {
        parameters {
            stringParam("KEY","VALUE")
        }
    }
```

But this way overwrites all other parameters in Job-B, because he creates a new job-B.
How can I change the selected parameters of another pipeline (Job-B) using Groovy?

Comment: Do you want to permanently change the parameter default values of another job or do you want to pass parameters to a run of another job (i. e. using `build` step)? It could be helpful if you explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to permanently change the parameter default values of another job.

Comment: To find some Groovy code, search for `ParametersDefinitionProperty`. If I find some time I will post an answer later.